# Google maps: Why is the polygon drawn wrong? And how can i fix this?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, polygon

I have loaded the google.maps in my application and i can draw polygons

In my application i check if a marker is inside a polygon.

I can't upload images yet, sadly. But i will trying to explain my problem. Look at this website at figure 2: http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/. There are two squares that are white. If i draw the same polygon on the map, only the right square is white. If i place a marker in de left square (that is grey in my application), the check returns false. What is correct! Only it looks like it's wrong because that square is like the rest of the polygon, except the right upper square, also gray.

I do everything with a drawingmanager:

```
  drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
        drawingModes: [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
        ]
    },
    //drawingMode: 'polygon',
    map: map
});
```

Now i want to know is how i can get that square white just like the square right above it?

Comment: What does your code look like?  How do you define the polygons?

Comment: I do everything with a drawingmanager. Check the update

Comment: What white square?  Are you talking about making ["holes" in the polygon](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polygon_example_donut.html)? I don't think the DrawingManager supports holes in polygons.

Comment: Holes is a better description then square's. In figure 2 on the website there are 2 holes. But when i draw the same polygon i only get 1 hole. But i want 2 holes. I don't get the hole on the left.

Comment: You probably need to reverse the "winding direction" of that inner polygon.

Comment: I searched on google but i can't find how to do this. Can you help me out?

Comment: [my quick and dirty "winding reversal tool"](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_winding_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/crues_450_windingFix_kml.xml) (works for polygons from KML)